# Type alias in SELinux

Tags: selinux, libselinux

I am using fedora 22. I have used a predifined type lets say a_t in .fc file. When I load the policy
and run restorecon -v . I get the following

restorecon reset  context b_t -> a_t

where b_t is the default context of .
but when I run ls -Z over that file it displays the older b_t.

Does it mean that a_t is an alias for b_t. I didn't get any definitive answer on this over internet

Answer (score 1):

As [selinuxproject.org](http://selinuxproject.org/page/TypeStatements#typealias) states:

> The typealias statement allows the association of a previously declared type to one or more alias identifiers (an alternative way is to use the type statement.